# Stop JQuery Mobile dialog from showing again when the back button is pressed

Tags: jquery-mobile

When I press the browser back button, my dialog shows again. How can I prevent this?

Html

```
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="page1">
        <a href="#dialog" data-rel="dialog">click me</a>
       ....stuff...
    </div>
    <div  data-dialog="true" data-role="dialog" id="dialog">
        <a href="#" data-bind="click: function () { goToPage2() }">go to p2</a>
       ....stuff...
    </div>
    <div data-role="page" id="page2">
       ....stuff...
    </div>
</body>
```

Model:

```
function UserViewModel() {
    self.startEvacuation = function () {
        $.mobile.navigate("#page2");
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you use the popup widget instead of dialogs? http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/popup/

Comment: Thanks ezanker I had missed that.